# What are the arguments against Mono? Does the Microsoft Community Promise change anything?

Tags: mono

In my research for getting Banshee to compile for Windows, I stumbled on [this post](http://www2.apebox.org/wordpress/rants/153/). It seems there still lives a LOT of suspicion towards Mono in the Linux community for being a timebomb Microsoft has put under FOSS.

A few days back I read Microsoft released their [Community Promise](http://www.microsoft.com/interop/cp/default.mspx) as to defuse these fears. Yet it seems not to be worth anything to developers.

I, as a C# developer, would love it to see my skills go cross platform. What exactly are the arguments against the Mono platform?

Comment: I see nothing about the legal position of mono in the post you linked to...

Comment: Please read the comments

Comment: Ah, perhaps you can be more specific in future.

Comment: Sure, no problem. So what are your sentiments after reading the comments?

Comment: It seems that the title of your question asks one thing, but the text of it (specifically the last sentence) asks a very different one. So which it is (or is it both)? In any case, the question in the title is something you should ask a lawyer, not fellow developers.

Comment: I rephrazed my title. Does that make more sence?

Comment: This question is too old to migrate, but for future reference it belongs on [programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 5):

The argument against Mono is based on a notion that using C# will make your code fall under Microsoft patents, but using something else will avoid Microsoft patents. In my IANAL opinion, there's no reason to believe that avoiding C# will decrease the likelihood of infringement.

Therefore, it seems to me that using Mono is safer than not using it, since at least C# is explicitly covered by the Community Promise. Any other alternative technology is covered by nothing, and therefore is more at risk of liability.

Answer (score 3):

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29#Mono_and_Microsoft.E2.80.99s_patents) pretty much explains the current legal situation. See the [Microsoft Community Promise](http://www.microsoft.com/interop/cp/default.mspx) for how much it covers. So from a legal point of view, you should be safe using Mono but you can still be sued for technology you develop (as usual).

On the positive side, developing with Mono should make your code usable for more people.

On the negative side, Mono will always lag behind .NET. Mono will never be 100% compatible ,which might bite you in areas where it doesn't lag behind. Mono also has a bad reputation within the Linux community (i.e. they're labelled as "traitors" bringing Evil(TM) to the free world).

Comment: Well the reason to be suspicious has to do with intention. C# considered on it's own isn't bad but neither is swinging a bat. If you swing the bat at someones head, it's generally considered bad. The technical people who developed C# just want to make the best language they can, the people who financed it and control the lawyers have a different goal: History http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Java_Virtual_Machine search for "destroy the cross-platform threat entirely" then look the the second fork of the strategy the development of the C# language (2002)

Comment: So they immediately after resolving their court case with sun (2001), showing that they were at the time strongly adamant towards undermining the "cross platform threat", they then (2002) release a language they funded which purports to do what Java does? As others mention other platforms will _always_ be second class citizens. No one is going to cheer for second class. Sun supported all platforms at once, there is no reason C# could not be platform independent too, but by design (not technical but business choice) this is intentional.

Answer (score 1):

It'll always be lagging behind?

Don't get me wrong I love the idea of mono, just trying to think of possible arguments against

Comment: As I understand from the post I linked to, it seems that the fear is more towards a legal problem.

Comment: Not sure if it always will. It started after .net on Windows but as far as I know they will support C# 4.0 when it's released. Most important libraries are supported.

Comment: @boris I would not expect Microsoft to sue Mono, Microsoft wants .net to be platform-independant. For more information you can listen to the latest SO podcast: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/podcast-61/

Comment: The question is not will, but more "could". I can see the fears for oss devs to see their hard work be confiscated because MS plays it's joker.

Comment: @weiqure: mono is always going to be in a reactive position, so it will always lag.

I seriously doubt MS wants .net to be truly platform-independent. They just want it to look that way. Their handling of ODF in office is a nice example of this trick: http://homembit.com/2009/05/microsoft-now-attempt-to-fragment-odf.html

Comment: Sure, they will lag some. But you can weigh it against the cross platform factor. But I don't think that is the biggest gripe at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's track record with respect to open source and competitors in general, is one of the strongest arguments against Mono, due to Microsoft patents.

Microsoft has promised not to sue, but the patents are still there, and there might be other ways for them to be activated.

Comment: Can you back your statement up somehow? Isn't that what the CTP is all about?

Comment: The problem is that the MCP only covers parts of what is considered ".NET". Since mono implements a lot more than those core parts, there's nothing that stops MS from sueing them on those other parts.

Comment: Boris, this is purely speculation, it's the nature of this kind of thing, please remember that. For example, Microsoft has promised not to sue OSS projects over these patents. They haven't promised not to sell the patents to a company that will sue. So as long as the patented technology is there, OSS projects will have a degree of uncertainty to take care of.

Comment: IANAL. The likelyhood to be sued is directly proportional to the amount of money that can be expected as revenue as the result of the lawsuit. So unless you're a company or really rich, no sane person is going to drag a single OSS developer into court. OSS teams as a whole are pretty safe because they are not in a single place. OTOH, an OSS project can be stopped with a single C&D letter because the individuals can't afford to see a lawyer to defend against it. So patents aren't the real issue, but the claims which can be derived from them.

Comment: True, but the thread can vastly hamper adoption. Less adoption means less support and will make the whole x-platform initiative die a slow death. I think we can all agree that one of the important factors of a technology lies in it's community and support (the reason we are on this website in the first place)

Comment: I have had microsoft partner vendors explain to me that we shouldn't use Linux because of the SCO lawsuit since all Linux users could be sued if SCO proved IBM had used their code.  I laughed another company might have believed them.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds pretty good for the parts of mono covered by the specifications mentioned. It does boil down to "We won't sue you." It doesn't mean they won't compete with you nor slander you as ingenuine. Also it doesn't promise what other licensees of their patents might do, though I think they wouldn't have much of a case given the promise.

It clearly states that if they get sued, they no longer abide to the promise for the party that is suing them. So if someone invented something patentable that is under the specs, and they patent it, Microsoft can start using it without having to worry about getting sued for patent infringement, because if they do, they can similarly sue. It's actually a lot friendlier than it sounds.

Basically the promise is contingent on a mutual agreement not to sue.

Comment: Lots of Sues there. Can you furhter explain your last paragraph? Do I interpret it right if I think you say their promise actually turns the table around? It enables MS to use the things that come out of Mono without being sued?

Comment: Yes the promise is contingent on mutual agreement.